# Why does Vim create ~ files?

Tags: save, file

Whenever I create a file, Vim also creates a `.extension~` file. For example, when I create a `main.cpp` file, another one appears with `main.cpp~`. Is the `.cpp~` file an older version of my `.cpp` file? Is there any reason to why Vim does this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Do you happen to have the `'backup'` option enabled? You can check that with `:verbose set backup?`, which will tell you whether you have it on, and also where in your configs it was enabled.

Comment: Adding to @filbranden's comment, read up on the help docs in vim. You can bring it up by pressing `:help backup` in vim. You can disable backup by pressing `:set nobackup` in vim or by adding the line `set nobackup` in your vimrc (typically resides in your home folder).